# Extending the notion of convex hull in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: convex-analysis

The super convex hull of a set $A \subseteq \Bbb R^n$, is the set of all $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_i x_i$ such that $\lambda_i \geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_i =1$, which is denoted by cco(A). It is easily verified that $co(A) \subseteq cco(A) \subseteq  {\bf cl}\big(co(A)\big)$.
Is the equality hold?
((i.e. $co(A) = cco(A)$?))

Note that for $n=1$  the assertion holds, and wherever $A$ is a subset of an infinite intentional Banach space, then the equality dose not necessarily satisfy.

{the notion of super convex hull is defined in the complete and excellent book "Banach space theory", by Marian Fabian, Peter Habala, and et al}